# Does Nifi-1.10.0 support transaction when consuming messages in Kafka-2.x?

Tags: apache-kafka, transactions, apache-nifi

I check information but can't be sure whether ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_0 support transaction when consuming messages in Kafka-2.x?If it doesn't,this means that the offest in Kafka has changed as soon as messages will be consumed by Nifi,even if the transaction isnot commit?How to improve?

Thanks in advances

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Setting **Honor Transactions** to `true` (the default value) means that NiFi will only receive messages from Kafka when the transaction is complete. The Kafka topic offset will not change until the transaction is completed, at which point NiFi will receive the messages. If the transaction is canceled, NiFi will not receive any of the messages.

Comment: Thanks.But i am not quite sure why Honor Transaction describes the information about transations for producer instead of what you said.

Comment: If NiFi is acting as the consumer, that means the external Kafka system is acting as (or contains) the producer. So if the producer (i.e. the Kafka participant, not NiFi) cancels the transaction, NiFi will not _consume_ any of those messages.